# "module" object has no attribute error when using make_scorer and pipleline

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I get an error saying:
"module" object has no attribute quadratic_weighted_kappa" when running the code in ipython notebook from the following site 
https://www.kaggle.com/abhishek/crowdflower-search-relevance/beating-the-benchmark/code

It works when I build it in sublimetext but I cant get it to run in an ipython notebook without getting that error. What is the reasoning behind this and is there a way I can fix it?